# Rmarkdown: objeto não encontrado ao usar knitr

Tags: rmarkdown

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esto tentando criar um arquivo do word a partir do Rmarkdown usando knitr, mas em uma determinada linha(ver na imagem) não encontra o objeto iris.wide, mas no console roda normalmente. Por que isso acontece e como resolver? Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Você cria `iris.wide` no documento? Dentro do código do markdown?

Comment: Não, foi importado. Opa, então mesmo importando tenho que colocar o código de importação no Rmarkwdown?

Comment: Sim, tudo que você cria ou usa no markdown você tem que criar/importar. Ele roda numa sessão "zerada", então não usa nada que você cria fora dele.

Comment: Se você não quer que a importação apareça no documento é só usar `include = FALSE` na caixa de código.

Comment: Jorge, muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente! Aconteceu a mesma coisa com outros conjuntos de dados, mas agora sei como resolver graças você.